# How does google cloud shell allocate RAM and Cores?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I have recently started to host a minecraft server on google cloud shell using https://github.com/lordofwizard/mcserver , and its all well untill we check the specs, my friends when cheking on his account has 16 GB of ram and 2 cores , but i only have 8 GB of ram and 1 core , there is no other alt account of mine which got the 16 GB ram and 2 core machine, any idea how does google cloud shell gives its users ram and is it possible to change the amount it gives , Note this is for the non-paid version of google cloud shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to modify the memory nor CPU on the Cloud Shell. If you need something more, please create a VM using Compute Engine where you can modify it to your needs.

You can run `free -h` to see the size of memory.

According to the [Github page](https://github.com/lordofwizard/mcserver#mixed-server-specs) you linked to it says this:

> Each Cloud Shell session will have different specs of your server
> based on your physical location so you won't always get the best
> performance of your server but good news being that it's always the
> range between 8GB to 16GB so you won't have to worry about lag when
> playing in the server with high processing in your server.